# cannot test static asset

Tags: unit-testing, playframework, sbt

For a scala project I'm using the [test documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaTestingYourApplication) to test this very simple controller that simply return a static asset

```scala
class HomeController @Inject() extends Controller {
  def index() =
    controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public/data", "afile.json")
}
```

I started to made the following test for testing the json file :

```scala
import org.scalatestplus.play.PlaySpec
import org.scalatestplus.play.guice.GuiceOneAppPerSuite
import play.api.http.Status
import play.api.test.FakeRequest
import play.api.test.Helpers._

class HomeControllerSpecTest extends PlaySpec with GuiceOneAppPerSuite {
  "HomeController" should {
    "render the index page" in {
      val home = route(app, FakeRequest("GET","/index/")).get
      status(home) mustBe Status.OK
    }
  }
}
```

When starting the serveur and checking with the browser the asset is well send/received BUT the test failed because of 404 status.

How assets can be tested ?

Comment: Could you show `routes` file?

Comment: ```GET     /index/                                         controllers.HomeController.index```